# recorrer un list en jsp

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

tengo un resulset guardado en una lista, la lista la pase a una jsp por medio de un servlet, con esa lista lleno un select y dependiendo de ese select (name = nomFuent) se debe autocompletar un input (name="nitfuente"), como puedo hacerlo.

servlet

```
String Numasociado = request.getParameter("nitbuscar");
             Consultas con = new Consultas();

             List <NumRecibo> lista = con.cosulFuentesAsociado(Numasociado);


          request.setAttribute("listado", lista);
          request.getRequestDispatcher("/ingreso.jsp").forward(request, response)
```

;

```
jsp 



 <%-- 
        Document   : ingreso
        Created on : 20/07/2016, 12:59:42 PM
        Author     : jefma
    --%>


    <%@page import="Controlador.NumRecibo"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="resource/img/index.ico"/>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
            <title>Generar Recibo</title>
            <link href="resource/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <link href="resource/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <script src="resource/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="resource/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="resource/js/main.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <%!  int contador = 2;%>
            <div class = "container">
                <div  class="page-header page-header2 text-left">
                    <img src="resource/img/logo.png" class="img-responsive " alt="Responsive image"/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 ">
                    <div class="text-right col-md-7 ">
                        <h3 class="media-heading colorsub"><b>Generar Ingreso</b> </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-right col-md-5 ">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-defaul btn-primary2 " type="button" onclick="history.back()">Regresar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12" style = "margin-top:120px">


                    <div class="col-md-12 ">
                        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                            <label  class="control-label ">Razon social:</label>
                            <select  id="nomFuent" name="nomFuent" class="form-control"required >
                                <option> </option>  
                                <%
                                    List<NumRecibo> lista = (List<NumRecibo>) request.getAttribute("listado");

                                    int i = 0;
                                    for (NumRecibo numRecibo : lista) {

                                        String nombrefuente = (numRecibo.getNombre());
                                        out.println("<option value=" + nombrefuente + ">" + nombrefuente + "</option>");
                                    }

                                %>


                            </select>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                            <label  class="control-label  ">Nit Fuente:</label>

                            <% for (NumRecibo numRecibo : lista) {
                                    i++;
                                    int t = lista.size();

                                    int con = contador;
                           if (con == i) {
                               String nit = (numRecibo.getNit());%>
                            <input type="inputtext" class="form-control" id="nit" placeholder="NIT" value="<%=nit%>" disabled="disabled" name="nitfuente" />
                            <%}
                                if (i == t) {
                                    String nitA = (numRecibo.getNitAsociado());
                                    String nom = (numRecibo.getNomAsociado());
                            %>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                            <label  class="control-label  ">Nit Asociado:</label>         

                            <input type="inputtext" class="form-control" id="nit" placeholder="NIT" value="<%=nitA%>" disabled="disabled"  />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                            <label  class="control-label ">Nombre Asociado:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Razonsocial" placeholder="Razon social" value="<%=nom%>"disabled="disabled">
                        </div><%}
                            }%>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12" style = "margin-top:120px">

                    <table id="tablaMateriales" class="table table-bordered" >
                        <thead>

                            <tr>
                                <th rowspan="2" scope="col">No</th>

                                <th rowspan="2" scope="col ">Clase Residuo</th>
                                <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Tipo Residuo</th>
                                <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Cantida Kilos</th>
                                <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Valor Unitario</th>
                                <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Valor Total</th>


                                <th colspan="2" scope="col">Rechazo</th>
                            </tr>

                            <tr> 
                                <th scope="col"  >Kilos</th>
                                <th scope="col">Valor</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-sm-1 ">1</td>
                                <td class="col-sm-2 "><select id="tipomaterial" name="tipomaterial" class="form-control ">
                                        <option value="0" selected="selected"> </option>
                                        <option value="M" >Metales </option>
                                        <option value="PC" >Papel-Carton</option>
                                        <option value="PL" >Plasticos</option>
                                        <option value="V" >Vidrio</option>
                                        <option value="R" >Reuso</option>
                                        <option value="RE" >Retoma</option>

                                    </select></td>
                                <td class="col-sm-2 "><select id="tiporesiduo" name="tiporesiduo" class="form-control ">

                                    </select></td></td>
                                <td class="col-sm-1 "><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                <td class="col-sm-1 "><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                <td class="col-sm-2 "><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                <td class="col-sm-1 "><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                <td class="col-sm-2 "><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                <td class="text-center">

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>    
                    </table>
                    <table id ="tablatotales" class="table table-bordered table-responsive " >   

                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-sm-1">
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-5">
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-2 active col colorstit">
                                Sub Total 
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-2 active col">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-sm-1">
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-5">
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-2 active col colorstit">
                                IVA 
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-2 active col">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td  class="col-sm-1">
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-5">
                            </td>
                            <td  class="col-sm-2 active col colorstit">
                                Total 
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-2 active col">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class= "tamanobotton btn btn-primary btn-defaul" id="btnnuevo">Nuevo</div>
                </div>



                <div class="col-md-12 ">
                    <div  class="page-header text-center page-header2">
                        <img src="resource/img/logo2.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Responsive image"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>  

    </html>
```

Comment: Dos cosas: 1) No utilices scriptlets, para eso has importado las librerías de JSTL de manera que tu página queda limpia de código Java. 2) No se puede ver claramente en qué parte de tu página necesitas acceder a los elementos de esta lista para auto completar información, veo que utilizas la lista para generar el contenido de un `<select>` y luego otra lógica con un contador que no tiene sentido puesto que Java se ejecutará de lado del servidor, no del cliente (¿quizás aquí sea donde quieres activa la opción auto completar?).

Comment: me explico mejor la list contine (nombrefuente,nitfuente,nitsocio,nombresocio) con el nombre de la fuente lleno la seleccion una vez seleccione se debe llenar el campo input name"nit fuente" con el campo de la lista nitfuente pero debe corresponde a la fuente que se selecciono

Comment: Oh ok. Para cualquier funcionalidad de lado del cliente debes utilizar JavaScript, no Java. Java (lo mismo con .Net, PHP, Python, Ruby, `<pon otro lenguaje de programación aquí>`) se ejecuta de lado del servidor para generar HTML. De lado del cliente, solo se ejecuta JavaScript (asumiendo que el cliente no lo ha deshabilitado).

Answer (score 1):

lo que realice fue una función con jquery que me redirecciona a otra jsp que ejecuta la consulta  a la bd y me devuel dentro de la misma función el resultado de la consulta

jsp

```
<label  class="control-label  ">Nit Fuente:</label>
                        <input type="hidden" name="i_opc" id="i_opc">
                        <select id="nitfuentes" name="nitfuente" class="form-control"required >
                            <option value="">seleccione</option>
                        </select>
```

jquery

```
$("select[name=nomFuent]").change(function(){
    $("#f_opc").val("1");
    $.post("combo.jsp",$("#ingresom").serialize(),function(data){$("#nitfuentes").html(data);});

        });
```

2jsp

```
    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="modelo.Consultas"%>
<%String nom= request.getParameter("nomFuent");%>


<% String co = "SELECT * FROM `fuentes` WHERE `nom_Fuente` = '"+nom+"' ORDER BY `contacto_fuente`" ;
Consultas con = new Consultas();
String nit = con.nitfuentes(co);
System.out.print(nit);
%>
<select name="nitfuentes" >
    <option value="<%=nit%> "> <%=nit%></option>                              
                        </select>
```